# Using Microsoft R Server packages (e.g., RevoScaleR) with RStudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio-server, microsoft-r

I am using Microsoft R Server (MRS 8.0.5) on a Hadoop cluster. MRS packages (RevoScaleR, RevoPemaR) work well at the command line, but I can't use them with RStudio Server. It seems these packages are not available for Rstudio server. Other packages (such as RevoIOQ, RevoMods) are OK. 
This might be a configuration issue, but there is no other versions of R on my cluster, only Microsoft R Open (MRO) for MRS.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: By using RStudio Server, do you mean, you're logging into the edge node? Everything should work with the local compute context. Actually using Hadoop (ie, the RxHadoopMR compute context) is something else.

Comment: I'm trying now on a small cluster as an experiment: one NameNode and two Data nodes. I installed RStudio Server & MRS on the NameNode. I know it is not a good way to have those two servers on the NameNode, but I'm trying to test this environment before moving to a bigger cluster. The problem is that I can't use MRS packages in Rstudio Server IDE. I get an error when I write:
> library(RevoScaleR)
Error in library (RevoScaleR) : there is no package called RevoScaleR?
Compute contexts are working at the command line. I'm not sure if there is another way to manage such environment.

Comment: Your MRS install may have expired. Try contacting tech support or your friendly Microsoft account manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which R installation you want to use with RStudio server. Follow this instruction: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R, look for this:

`export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R`

Situation will be a bit different if you have a Cloudera Parcel-based installation of Microsoft R Server. In that case I suggest looking at: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/235841328-Using-RStudio-Server-with-Microsoft-R-Server-for-Cloudera

Good luck!